# Хранение набора чекбоксов

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ситуация: в БД есть связующая таблица прав (id_user, id_operation) - юзеру с id_user доступна операция id_operation. Рассмотрим одного юзера. Пусть всего существует 5 записей операций. Но юзеру назначены 1,2,4 например. Админ хочет поменять набор прав. Ему выводится 5 чекбоксов, из которых 1-ый, 2-ой и 4-ый отмечены:

1.[y], 2.[y], 3.[ ], 4.[y], 5[ ]

Он меняет на:

1.[y], 2.[y], 3.[ ], 4.[ ], 5[y]

И хочет сохранить. На сервер придет: 1,2,5. Это и надо обновить в БД. Но я же не знаю что изменилось, т.е. что добавить, а что удалить. Как минимизировать затраты ресурсов на изменение? В голову приходят несколько вариантов:

1. Самое простое - получить снова все 5 записей и сравнить что изменилось. Новые отмеченные добавить, а снятые чекбоксы удалить. Не хочется опять запросы делать. Всегда стараюсь минимизировать их количество.
2. Сохранить перед выводом набор в сессию. И по схеме из п.1 (только без запросов в БД). Но не знаю, насколько хорошо хранить данные в сессии? Вероятно, это будет 20-30 id_operation. Чем это может быть чревато?
3. Еще неплохой вариант, повесить аякс на oncheck чекбокса и отправлять id_operation и состояние с которого изменен. Был отмечен? Удаляем! Не был? Добавляем! Это вроде логично, но не нравится как это отразится на понятливости интерфейса. Снял/отметил, а изменилось ли оно, юзеру может быть непонятно. А на каждое изменение выкидывать сообщение об успешном сохранении - тоже не вариант.
4. Записать первоначальный набор в скрытые поля. К каждому чекбоксу например, прикрутить скрытое поле с его состоянием.
5. Хм, пришел в голову еще один вариант. На каждого юзера хранить 1 строку с перечислением набора id операций. Т.е. хранил: 1,2,4. Пришли данные, и строку заменил на: 1,2,5. Экономия записей в БД "налицо".

Вот метаюсь, не знаю что выбрать. Что посоветуете? Приветствуются и свои варианты.

Comment: **- На спичках экономите.**

- Напишите хороший код (ваше состояние чекбоксов - это некоторое состояние модели, следовательно, для него можно придумать способ сериализации, следовательно, вы можете решить задачу в лоб, записав этот стейт в `BLOB`).

- Если в реальных сценариях работы такое решение будет работать недостаточно быстро (вдруг вы спрашиваете такие вопросы, а на деле `highload` проекты дизайните `:)`, то только тогда уже будет иметь смысл что-нибудь оптимизировать.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, highload или нет мне неизвестно)) Поэтому стараюсь расценивать и проектировать так, чтоб надежно)

Comment: @savro, пользователи точно будут добавляться, а привилегии часто будут изменяться. Я смею прикинуть, что их будет где-то 30-50. Скорее всего воспользуюсь вариантом 5.

Comment: костыль на костыле будет.

Тогда делайте 3 столбца, ид юзера, ид привилегии, и состояние активно или нет.

а потом или **UPSERT** (Oracle) или **Insert Or Update** (Firebird \IB)  или **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** (MySQL) в зависимости от выбранной Вами СУБД

Comment: @savro, и хранить 30 записей id привелегий на каждого юзера, из которых реально может быть назначено лишь несколько? Как-то нехорошо. Вроде совсем хромых костылей не наблюдаю. Получаю одним запросом строку с id-ками операций через запятую. Сделаю замену запятых на __or id_operation =__ и добавляю к __select * from operations where__ для получения инфы об операциях.

Comment: Вы читали что я писал?
Используйте **UPSERT** (или то что соответствует Вашей СУБД), то есть реально если у пользователя не было привилегии то и записи нет, если есть привилегия то и запись есть, если была но сейчас не активна то запись есть.
То есть записей будет столько сколько есть привилегий, + те привилегии что были но сейчас не активны.
Тем более ни кто не мешает, в какой то момент времени (обслуживание продукта) просто удалить те записи где опция привилегии не активна.

Comment: @savro, я как раз и подумал, что удаляться они не будут. Но все же это действительно хороший вариант. Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ - помечу правильным. Спасибо за терпение и помощь!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На сервер придет: 1,2,5. Это и надо обновить в БД. Но я же не знаю что изменилось, т.е. что добавить, а что удалить. Как минимизировать затраты ресурсов на изменение?

Команда UPDATE есть такая при работе с базой вот ее и используйте.

Тогда делайте 3 столбца, ид юзера, ид привилегии, и состояние активно или нет.

а потом или UPSERT (Oracle) или Insert Or Update (Firebird \IB) или ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (MySQL) в зависимости от выбранной Вами СУБД

Comment: @savro, так она не поможет мне) Мне нечего апдейтить. Если чекбокс был и его сняли - DELETE, если не было и добавили - INSERT. UPDATE можно было бы, если бы я сразу юзеру сохранил весь набор операций с флагами 0 или 1 - назначено или нет. Тогда я все пришедшие установил в 1, а что не пришли в 0. Но это не логично, т.к. нужно много записей хранить.

Comment: а какая у вас архитектура ? покажите кусок таблицы.

Логичней было бы  user_id int, Priv_1 bool, Priv_2 bool, Priv_3 bool

Comment: @savro, количество операций неизвестно. Просто привел практический пример, чтоб люди вникли. По поводу архитектуры: есть таблица юзеров с id\_user - описывает юзера не суть какими полями; есть таблица операций с id\_operation - запись: единица доступа. Например, "доступ к комментированию" (id\_operation=1); Связующая таблица прав с 2 полями: id\_user и id\_operation. Хранит например, 1|1 - юзеру с id=1 доступна операция с id\_operation=1

Comment: а почему не использовать вариант что я предложил выше.
в таблице ид юзера, и данные ему права.
в крайнем случае битовой маской воспользуйтесь

Comment: @savro, потому что я не знаю сколько таких операций будет создано и назначено. Битовая маска? Как вариант конечно, но уж лучше тогда пункт 5. Он понятнее и им проще оперировать.

Comment: чтож там страшного:

Привилегия 1 =1

Привилегия 2 =2

Привилегия 3 =4

Привилегия 4 =8

Привилегия 5 =16


если пользователю ид1 доступны 1,2,5 то в базе запись
ид1=19 (1+2+16)
хотим изменить например убрать 5 добавить 3 то делаем UPDATE ид1=7 (1+2+4)

Тут Вам и экономия на количестве записей и на запросах и на апдейтах.

а расшифровывать тоже просто:

х(переменая где значение привилегий)
 
if x>16 then { priv5=true;x=x-16}
if x>8 then (priv4=true;x=x-8}
if x>4 then (priv3=true;x=x-4}
if x>2 then (priv2=true;x=x-2}
if x>1 then (priv1=true;x=x-1}

Comment: @savro, я не говорю, что там что-то страшное. С ней мороки много. Всего с 5 операциями, а уже код "плохо" выглядит. Операции могут постоянно обновляться, т.е. их id (AUTO_INCREMENT) будет постоянно расти. Оперировать будет сложно и возможно это не будет быстро. Косяков потом может повылетать...

Comment: У Вас привилегии будут добавляться? или пользователи?

Answer (score 0):

Оптимально было бы хранить набор прав одного юзера как битовую маску: одно целое число. Один бит - одна операция, 1 - "разрешена", 0 - "запрещена". Вместо нескольких записей, всего одна:  `user_id (int), rights (int)`.

Но раз у вас уже существует другая схема, то так: прочитать из БД все права придётся в любом случае. Можно получить в одну строку все права пользователя:

```
SELECT
    SUM(1 - ABS( SIGN( id_operation - 1))) AS `operation_1`,
    SUM(1 - ABS( SIGN( id_operation - 2))) AS `operation_2`,
    SUM(1 - ABS( SIGN( id_operation - 3))) AS `operation_3`,
    SUM(1 - ABS( SIGN( id_operation - 4))) AS `operation_4`,
    SUM(1 - ABS( SIGN( id_operation - 5))) AS `operation_5`
FROM tbl_permissions
WHERE id_user = 12345
GROUP BY id_user
```

Запросить придётся дважды: при выводе чекбоксов, и перед сохранением, чтобы получить разницу. Но повторяющийся запрос скорее всего закешируется сервером БД и не создаст заметной нагрузки.

Из этой строки получите 1 или 0 для каждой из операций, сравните с пришедшими данными, и обновите, где они не совпали.

Comment: это уже предлагалось мной раньше, но у него беда в том что количество привилегий 30-50 и они могут добавляться динамически.